# Hyperlinks on CSS-transitions/transforms (scale) not opening

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Having issue with hyperlinks not being clickable when hovering over an element with a scale effect. [On this page](http://chemistrytable.dx.am/table.php), there is a Li element (Lithium, not li tag) I'm experimenting with. The links need to be clickable.

```css
.cell {
 display:inline-block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 5.55%;
  height: 100%;
 .transition(all 200ms ease);
 
}

.element  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
  .transition(all 200ms ease);
 
  
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.6);
}

.cell:hover .element {
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  .transform(scale(1.8,1.8));
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 128, 0.9);
}

.links_on_hover{
 display:inline-block;
 
 
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
      <div class="element">
        <div class="at_num">3</div>
        <div class="symbol"><a id="links_on_hover" href="elements/eng/Li.php">Li</a></div>
        <div class="at_details">lithium<br />6.94</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.element {
    ... 
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

This property disables mouse clicks, even for its children.